# is JDK required for Tomcat

Tags: jsp, java-8, tomcat8

My customers are using apache tomcat 8.5.14. currently the java is pointed to JDK directly.

Since oracle 8 is becoming commercial, is it ok to point to JRE ?

my customers are small time users and cant afford commercial JDK

Since many java files are using oracle 8 JDK, i fear changing to OpenJDK, may require extensive testing and migrating time is also not there.

there is no development happening at customer environment, its only tomcat which is using java / simple jsp.

please advise.

Comment: The version 8 of the Oracle SDK is not "becoming commercial". And the OpenJDK and the Oracle JDK are basically identical, except for some proprietary tools.

Answer (score 0):

Although Tomcat 8 need [JDK](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html):

> Tomcat can be run as a daemon using the jsvc tool from the commons-daemon project. Source tarballs for jsvc are included with the Tomcat binaries, and need to be compiled. Building jsvc requires a C ANSI compiler (such as GCC), GNU Autoconf, **and a JDK**.
>
> Before running the script, the JAVA_HOME environment variable should be set to the base **path of the JDK**. Alternately, when calling the ./configure script, the path of the JDK may be specified using the --with-java parameter, such as ./configure --with-java=/usr/java.

Oracle 8 **isn't** becoming commercial, there will be changes in [oracle license](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jdk-releases-for-java-11-and-later) in **next java versions**.

> Starting with Java 11, Oracle will provide JDK releases under the open source GNU General Public License v2, with the Classpath Exception (GPLv2+CPE), and under a commercial license for those using the Oracle JDK as part of an Oracle product or service, or who do not wish to use open source software.  This combination of using an open source license and a commercial license replaces the historical “BCL” license, which had a combination of free and paid commercial terms.

Answer (score 0):

Hello user7294900 (I have no reputation to comment directly). I think you are not right, especially if I read this FAQ https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-faqs.html here:

> For what uses is Oracle Java SE, including Java 8 updates, free?
>
> For full information and terms, refer to the OTN License Agreement for Java SE. The OTN License Agreement for Java SE for current Oracle Java SE releases allows them to be used, without cost:
>
> (i)    For personal use on a desktop or laptop computer, such as to play games or run other personal applications.
> (ii)    For development, testing, prototyping, and demonstrating applications, including to use by/with profilers, debuggers, and Integrated Development Environment tools.
> (iii)    For use with some approved products, such as Oracle SQL Developer, or as an  end user of a software application created by an approved product. (referred to as “Schedule A” and “Schedule B” Products in the OTN License Agreement for Java SE)
> (iv)    With identified Oracle Cloud Infrastructure products.

and here:

> Can you elaborate on what qualifies as Personal use?
>
> Personal use is using Java on a desktop or laptop computer to do things such as to play games or run other personal applications. If you are using Java on a desktop or laptop computer as part of any business operations, that is not personal use. For example, you could use a Java productivity application to do your own homework or your personal taxes, but you could not use it to do your business accounting.

I think this change runs after jdk 8u202.